# Update and check vs Select with holdlock

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We need to update a set of tables and this should be done in the scope of 1 transaction.

My colleague suggests the following approach

```
Begin Tran
Declare @tmp Table  (id int);

    UPDATE  tbl1
    SET     --set some fields
        ,   [Status] = 3
    Output  deleted.Status
    Into    @tmp        
    WHERE   ID = @Given_ID
        AND [Status] = 7



    If  Exists( SELECT  1 
                FROM    @tmp
                WHERE   id = 7)
    BEGIN
       -- Do some other updates and inserts
       .....
    Commit Tran
    RETURN 1
    END

    rollback Tran
    RETURN 0
```

My suggestion is to do as follows

```
 Begin tran
    If Exists( SELECT   1 
                FROM    tbl1 WITH (updlock, holdlock)
                WHERE   [status] = 7 AND ID=@Given_ID)
    BEGIN
    UPDATE  tbl1
    SET     ...
        ,   [Status] = 3        
    WHERE   ID = @Given_ID
        AND [Status] = 7

       -- Do some other updates and inserts
       .....
   Commit tran
   Return 1
    END

   rollback Tran
   RETURN 0
```

Could you please point which approach is better and explain why?
Can we do any better?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just try it in your test environment and find out. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" - Donald Knuth.

Comment: `begin tran`
     `SELECT *  tbl1 WITH(updlock, holdlock) WHERE TradeId=3`
      `update tbl1  SET SellerID=12 Where TradeId=3`
  `commit tran`
Works fine!

Comment: Your colleague's suggestion does exactly what you do but inserts some values into the @tmp table. Depending on the importance of that data (inserted values into tmp table) one can judge which approach is better.

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
I was worried about whether my colleague's suggestion was correct. Them I realized that since he's doing an update, the SQL Server will automatically lock that row. Thus, we do almost the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way to find out would be to take your two queries,
and put them into SQL Server Management studio, then push the button where it displays the estimated query plan. (or toggle the "display query plan" and then run the query...)

if both queries is run alongside one another, it will display the "cost" compared to one another. This of cause is only "best" in terms of performance. 
Both queries seems to lock into one transaction fine.

It is a matter of opinion when it comes to query formatting and method.